# Imported var on python/Django it's empty

Tags: python, django, import

I'm new with Django and I'm trying to access a varible from other file. But I don't get his value. I don't use DJango auth system, I log in to an IDP and the IDP send back the tokenId, uid plus some more data.

On the fileA.py I have:

```
.........
tokenId = ''
.........
def validateToken(tokenId):
      ...............
      returns True or False

def login(request):
     .............
     global tokenId
     tokenId = value/returned/from/server
     return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')
```

And when the user it's redirected, the code goes to fileB.py:

```
from fileA import validateToken, tokenId
.........
def menu(request):
    if validateToken(tokenId):
       return render_to_response('menu/menu.html')
    else:
       return render_to_response('menu/access_error.html')
```

If I do debug I discover that tokenId it's empty... but in fileA tokenId has his value assigned and I can use it to do the logout and works. So I don't understand why when I call tokenId from other file it has no value...

I tried to do the check on fileA:

```
def validateToken(): #I don't pass the var because it's global on fileA
    .........
    returns True or False
```

And on fileB I do:

```
from fileA import validateToken
.........
def menu(request):
    if validateToken():
       return render_to_response('menu/menu.html')
    else:
       return render_to_response('menu/access_error.html')
```

But it gives an error of: [NameError] name 'tokenId' it's not defined.

But it's defined! :/

What I'm doing wrong? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Even if you could get this to work, you **must not**. Any variable at module level is shared for all requests, so your `token_id` would be visible for other users. Don't do this.

Comment: So, how can I check that the token it's valid (the user did login) and show the protected content?

Comment: If you need to persist things across requests, you need to store them somewhere; probably the best place here would be the session.

Comment: Mmmm maybe I forgot say that I'm not using Django Auth system. I do the login to an IDP and the IDP sends to me the tokenId and the uid, plus some more data. Can I use anyway the DJango session?

Comment: I don't see how that's  relevant. This is user-specific data, it belongs in the session, which has no dependency on the Django auth system.

Comment: Ah ok, thanks. I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Daniel Roseman to give me the hint of use sessions. I have solved my problem.

On fileA I added:

```
def login(request):
   ...........
   global tokenId  <-------- deteled
   tokenId = value/returned/from/server
   request.session['tokenId'] = tokenId    <-------- added
   return HttpResponseRedirect('/loggedin')
```

And now, on fileB I put the validate function:

```
def validateToken(request):
    ...................
    request.session.get('tokenId') <---- when I need get the value

def menu(request):
   if validateToken(request):
      return render(request, 'menu/menu.html')
   else:
      return render_to_response('menu/access_error.html')
```